# Gtk Notebook tab size

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

I am using a gtkNotebook to show a number of widgets on the bottom of my app. The problem is that when the tabs are showing they take up a lot of space and look awkward in general. I figured out that it is cause by the `gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU` being bigger that the text, but I can't find any constants that are smaller and I don't want to give it a exact pixel size since it may mess up on different screen resolutions. Is the any way to get the button to always scalse to the size of the text on the label next to it?

Here is the code that generates the button (the hbox it's in is the widget that the tab displays):

```
    box = gtk.HBox(False,0)
    btn = gtk.Button()
    image = gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_CLOSE, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)
    btn.set_image(image)
    btn.set_relief(gtk.RELIEF_NONE)
    btn.show()

    if type(label) != type(gtk.Label()):
        label = gtk.Label('Untitled')
    box.pack_start(label)
    box.pack_end(btn)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to make the Close buttons smaller, have a look at how—for example—Epiphany removes most of the padding around the button.

- [Define the button style](http://git.gnome.org/browse/epiphany/tree/src/ephy-notebook.c?id=c255df464cf44e9687f80c5845e5f31a500f7084#n164) (in PyGTK, `gtk_rc_parse_string` is `gtk.rc_parse_string`);
- [Use it](http://git.gnome.org/browse/epiphany/tree/src/ephy-notebook.c?id=c255df464cf44e9687f80c5845e5f31a500f7084#n617) on all your Close buttons.

Result:

[image: Tabs in Epiphany, from http://projects.gnome.org/epiphany/images/customizable.png]

(This is a slightly older version of their code; Ephy trunk uses the GTK+ 3.0 CSS styling, but same idea.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you could do is

1. supply a custom widget for your notebook tab labels via [set_tab_label](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtknotebook.html#method-gtknotebook--set-tab-label)
2. use [set_size_request](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/2.19/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a5e95431f630a226b0b7297e4815ee945) to set label widget's size

See if an example below would work for you:

```
import gtk
import sys;

class TestNotebook(gtk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Notebook.__init__(self)

    def add_new_tab(self, icon):
        image = gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_stock(icon, gtk.ICON_SIZE_DIALOG)
        image.show_all()        

        tab_image = gtk.Image()
        tab_image.set_from_stock(icon, gtk.ICON_SIZE_MENU)

        box = gtk.HBox()
        box.pack_start(tab_image, False, False)
        box.pack_start(gtk.Label(icon), True, True)
        # set tab size here
        box.set_size_request(50, 50)        
        box.show_all()

        self.set_current_page(self.append_page(image))
        self.set_tab_label(image, box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    notebook = TestNotebook()
    notebook.add_new_tab(gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
    notebook.add_new_tab(gtk.STOCK_ADD)
    notebook.add_new_tab(gtk.STOCK_APPLY)

    box = gtk.VBox()
    box.pack_start(notebook)

    window = gtk.Window()
    window.resize(600, 400)
    window.add(box)
    window.show_all()

    gtk.main()
    sys.exit(0)
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Is there any way to know the standard height that an hbox with only text would have? I say that because I don't want to do the size request based on my resolution alone, but based on the size it would have had on the screen its on. Hope this made sense.

Comment: I guess you can check if Widget.size_request (http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--size-request) would work for you, regards

Answer (score 0):

More up to date answer of @erge_gubenko, when you're using a newer Python/Gtk version:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys

class TestNotebook(Gtk.Notebook):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Notebook.__init__(self)

    def add_new_tab(self, icon):
        image = Gtk.Image()
        image.set_from_icon_name(icon, Gtk.IconSize.DIALOG)
        image.show_all()        

        tab_image = Gtk.Image()
        tab_image.set_from_icon_name(icon, Gtk.IconSize.MENU)

        label = Gtk.Label(icon) # Deprecated
        box = Gtk.HBox()
        box.pack_start(tab_image, False, False, 2)
        box.pack_start(label, True, True, 2)
        # set tab size here
        box.set_size_request(50, 50)        
        box.show_all()

        self.set_current_page(self.append_page(image))
        self.set_tab_label(image, box)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    notebook = TestNotebook()
    notebook.add_new_tab(Gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
    notebook.add_new_tab(Gtk.STOCK_ADD)
    notebook.add_new_tab(Gtk.STOCK_APPLY)

    box = Gtk.VBox()
    box.pack_start(notebook, True, True, 2)

    window = Gtk.Window()
    window.resize(600, 400)
    window.add(box)
    window.show_all()

    Gtk.main()
    sys.exit(0)
```